# Array of JQuery Selectors

Tags: jquery, arrays

for convenience I wanted to be able to reference my JQuery selectors from an array rather than individually. I was led to believe that the following logic would enable me to do so:

```
var reference = $('.class');

reference[0].<function>;
```

instead of:

```
$reference1 = $('#id1');
$reference2 = $('#id2');
$reference3 = $('#id3');

$reference1.<function>
```

all of my elements have the appropriate class and are being populated into the array(?) but for some reason I can't then call JQuery functions from the array in the same way I can with a single selector. Is there something I'm missing or a reason I can't do this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/mWaRf/

this was the example I was basing it off.

Comment: It's not clear what you want - one jQuery collection or one per element?

Comment: You can use `.eq( index )` to create a jQuery object containing a single element, is that what you want?

Comment: I guess a JQuery collection? Although I'm new to this and don't know exactly what I'm talking about (obviously). I just want a single variable I can reference which stores (like an array) a JQuery reference to each instance of a specific class in my html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reference[0]` refers to an [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) instead of a jQuery object.

If you want to refer to the first object matching a selector, use [.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/):

```
/* This returns a jQuery object. */
reference.first();
```

If you want the object at index n, use '[:eq(n)](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)' in your selector, or the [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method. These are zero-indexed:

```
/* This returns a jQuery object. */
$('.class:eq(n)');
/* This returns a jQuery object. */
reference.eq(n);
```

You could also "re-wrap" an element, but this is not idiomatic:

```
/* This returns an Element. */
reference[n];
/* This returns a jQuery object. */
$(reference[n]);
```

Similarly, you could use [get](http://api.jquery.com/get/). But the methods above are preferable:

```
/* This returns an Element. */
reference.get(n);
/* This returns a jQuery object. */
$(reference.get(n));
```

What wrapping means:

This is our page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hey</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>You</p>
    <p>!!!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This creates a jQuery object named `$p`, selecting the two `<p>` [Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element):

```
/* This returns a jQuery object. */
var $p = $('p');
```

This object has all those useful jQuery methods we love:

```
$p.css('color', 'purple'); /* this colors all paragraphs purple */
```

Like I said, we can select the second (or first) paragraph with `.eq()`:

```
/* This returns a jQuery object. */
$p.eq(1); /* this selects the second paragraph (because indices start at 0) */
```

Or we could do it like you were trying to do:

```
/* This returns an Element. */
$p[1];
```

**But this gives us a plain old Element, and not a jQuery object.** However, if we apply the jQuery function, we get back a jQuery object, and we can use all our beloved jQuery methods:

```
$($p[1]).text('???');
```

Applying `$` again to an Element is what I called re-wrapping.

Comment: this was very helpful to know, with regards to the second option can I only use that to refer to specifically to the nth instance of class? and I'm not entirely sure what rewraping an element means I'm afraid, obvious rookie here.

Comment: Updated answer with additional explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example code doesn't works as `reference[0]` will fetch underlying DOM element and those doesn't have jQuery methods, thus you must be getting error.

[`.eq(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) can be used

> Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

Change your code as

```
var reference = $('.class');
reference.eq(0).fn()
```

Comment: I tried to use this exactly but I can't make it work for me. I'm using the velocity.js and blast.js libraries so when I call it it looks like: `reference.eq(0).blast({delimeter:"word}).velocity(...velocityFunction...);`

Comment: I can make exactly the same call when using `$reference1.blast({delimeter:"word}).velocity(...velocityFunction...);` which works fine for me. But I just don't want to have to declare a stupid amount of variables at the beginning of my js file.